# How to set textview text using JavaScript Android

Tags: javascript, android

I want to set text in textview in my android class using JavaScript which contains a same named variable as in the class for textview to which I want to assign some text. Something like this:

In js:

```
function validClick() {

 fromJS.append("vikrant");

 valid.performClick();

 document.getElementById("ok").value = "Accepte";
}
```

fromJS is my textview in android class.

and the code in the class looks like:

```
    valid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = fromJS.getText();
            CharSequence text = clsVariable;

            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
            

        }
    });
```

### Edit

Also, I'm writing

```
    wbvw.addJavascriptInterface(valid, "valid");
    wbvw.addJavascriptInterface(fromJS, "fromJS");
```

in my onCreate method.

Comment: Did you try using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface already..? If so, what exactly is your problem and/or question?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link. I think it uses TextView and javascript to lad data to it.

http://divineprogrammer.blogspot.in/2009/11/javascript-rhino-on-android.html

```
doit(
         "var widgets = Packages.android.widget;\n" +
         "var view = new widgets.TextView(TheActivity);\n" +
         "TheActivity.setContentView(view);\n" +
         "var text = 'Hello Android!\\nThis is JavaScript in action!';\n" +
         "view.append(text);"
         );
```